Should I prevent my cat from eating flies?
My cat has a thing for hunting flies and sometimes he'll stay in position for ten minutes waiting for the fly to come off from high ground so that he can hunt them but after hunting them he usually eats them and I am worried that he might get a disease or something similar from hunting flies. But when I prevent him from hunting things like bees he gets really frustrated. Should I try to prevent him from eating flies or is the risk not worth the stress it would cause?

If your cat is vaccinated or medicated to prevent  the usual insect-borne diseases such as heartworm, I don't  think there's significant additional risk from eating the insects, Just be glad it isn't mice.

your cat grooming after walking on the floor/ground do probably pose a bigger risk for our cats than eating some flies does.

Hunting bugs is good enrichment for your cat and can positively contribute to good mental health and behavior. Most are also harmless when eaten.  However, in most places there is some risk (exactly how much risk depends mostly on your climate/location and the type of bugs) of catching parasites or worms this way if he's also eating them.  You should also be aware that a few types of bugs are toxic or otherwise dangerous.
My personal perspective is to not interfere with the bug hunting/eating unless it's a biting, stinging or toxic bug, but to make sure my cats see the vet for at least an annual checkup and are dewormed on schedule.  Your vet may also recommend more than yearly deworming or a flea/tick/heartworm monthly treatment, which is particularly important for cats that hunt and eat any sort of wild creatures.
